How to connect to same in-memory sqlite database instance, with both sync and async sessions with sqlalchemy?
Is it possible (and if so, how ?) with sqlalchemy to have an instance of AsyncEngine and one of Engine pointing to the same in-memory sqlite database ?
I know it is possible with file databases, and I also know the default behavior when creating such engines when working in-memory is to create two distinct in-memory db. Is it possible to share the db, so that sessions and async sessions share the same DB and reflect each other changes ?
